# Install Mesa3D on Debian - LIBDRM not found by configure autoconf

Tags: debian, compiling, autotools

I am trying to compile and install mesa3D from source.
(ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/11.0.0/mesa-11.0.0-rc3.tar.gz)

I am at the `configure` step

```
./configure \
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g -DDEFAULT_SOFTWARE_DEPTH_BITS=31" \
CFLAGS="-O2 -g -DDEFAULT_SOFTWARE_DEPTH_BITS=31" \
--disable-xvmc \
--disable-glx \
--disable-dri \
--with-dri-drivers="" \
--with-gallium-drivers="swrast" \
--enable-texture-float \
--disable-shared-glapi \
--disable-egl \
--with-egl-platforms="" \
--enable-gallium-osmesa \
--enable-gallium-llvm=yes \
--with-llvm-shared-libs \
--prefix=/opt/mesa/11.0.0/llvmpip
```

I keep getting the error about `configure` not finding the `LIBDRM` library

```
checking for LIBDRM... no
configure: error: shared GLAPI required when building two or more of
                      the following APIs - opengl, gles1 gles2
```

Even though the library is known to `ldconfig`

```
ldconfig -p | grep drm
libdrm_radeon.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so.1
libdrm_radeon.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_radeon.so
libdrm_nouveau.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.1
libdrm_nouveau.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so
libdrm_intel.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so.1
libdrm_intel.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_intel.so
libdrm.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2
libdrm.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so
```

I tried to use the `LDFLAGS` env variable but without success

```
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' ./configure <my configure parameters here>
```

or

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" && ./configure <my configure parameters here>
```

Here is the part in the configure script (that I assume is) generating this error

```
# Check for libdrm

pkg_failed=no
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for LIBDRM" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for LIBDRM... " >&6; }

if test -n "$LIBDRM_CFLAGS"; then
    pkg_cv_LIBDRM_CFLAGS="$LIBDRM_CFLAGS"
 elif test -n "$PKG_CONFIG"; then
    if test -n "$PKG_CONFIG" && \
    { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors \"libdrm >= \$LIBDRM_REQUIRED\""; } >&5
  ($PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libdrm >= $LIBDRM_REQUIRED") 2>&5
  ac_status=$?
  $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  test $ac_status = 0; }; then
  pkg_cv_LIBDRM_CFLAGS=`$PKG_CONFIG --cflags "libdrm >= $LIBDRM_REQUIRED" 2>/dev/null`
                      test "x$?" != "x0" && pkg_failed=yes
else
  pkg_failed=yes
fi
 else
    pkg_failed=untried
fi
```

Could you provide some propositions or hints to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the -dev package installed for opengl, gles1, or gles2?

Comment: Nope. I am new to computer graphics, but from what I've read, mesa3D **is an implementation** of OpenGL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#Implementations). It is mostly used to render 3D graphics using processors where no openGL drivers are provided by hardware vendors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I manged to install Mesa3D from source on Debian.Thanks to all people's answers and comments.

First, I had to install `libdrm-dev` package.

```
# apt-get install libdrm-dev
```

Then, check where the header and lib files were installed

```
# dpkg-query -L libdrm-dev
...
/usr/include/libdrm/drm.h
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.a
...
```

After that, export two env variables needed by `configure` to link to `libdrm` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644211/mesa3d-install-cant-find-libdrm)

```
# export LIBDRM_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/libdrm/"
# export LIBDRM_LIBS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
```

Finaly,`configure`, `make` and `make install`

```
# ./configure <parameters here>
# make -j24 # running on a 24 cores machine
# make -j24 install
```

Otherwise, the second error I was getting,

```
configure: error: shared GLAPI required when building two or more of
                  the following APIs - opengl, gles1 gles2
```

was not linked to `libdrm`. It was because of `libgalpi` that shouldn't be disabled when running `configure`!

Answer (score 1):

The run-time libraries are installed, but per your comment response, the development packages are not - that's what the `./configure` error is complaining about. I'm not sure of the exact package name, you'll probably have to do an `apt-cache search` for it, but if you install the `-dev` package for libDRM, that should resolve this issue. You may run into another `-dev` package not installed error, just keep installing the required `-dev` packages until the `./configure` run completes.

Comment: As in my comment back to John, I don't think I need to install  an OpenGL package, because that is **exactly** what I am trying to configure and install from source. Mesa3D is an **actual** implementation of OpenGL interface.

Comment: @LokmanDz you don't need to install OpenGL packages, but you **do** need to install the development packages for Mesa's dependencies. (Look for "adep" on https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/mesa or just run `sudo apt-get build-dep mesa`.)

Comment: You're correct - I was getting confused in re-reading the initial post. You do, however, need to install development packages for the DRM libraries. I'll modify this answer to reflect that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries seen by `ldconfig` are used for runtime linking; compiling requires an extra symlink (and header files in most cases). In this instance you need to install `libdrm-dev`, and probably other `-dev` packages too.

You may find [How to build mesa](https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/build-mesa.html) useful; it explains in detail how to build Mesa from source in Debian.

Comment: That is true. `ldconfig` are used for run-time linking, thanks for the precision. Still, this shows that `libdrm` is well installed. As you have mentioned, I had to add symlink by exporting two env variables used by `configure`; `LIBDRM_CFLAGS` and `LIBDRM_LIBS` to compile `mesa` successfully.